# Why do I get so many errors when I use "npx expo start"

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

for my class I created a map named "test-app", but when I want to start my app with "npx expo start' i get alot of errors. [These are the errors that I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccS7s.png)

- I tried to reinstall node ( I have now node version V20)
- npm install -g npm@latest ( I get error when I do this command)
- sudo npm install -g @expo/ngrok@^4.1.0 ( it tells me to upgrade to a higher version)
- And I did the install expo cli, nothing happened